# Cancan and polymorphism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, cancan, polymorphic-associations

I want to specify rules in ability file for polymorphic associations as follows:

```
 class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    if user.role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role? :author
      can :read, :all
      can :manage, [Post, Article], user_id: user.id
      can :manage, Comment, commentable: {user_id: user.id}        
    end
  end
end
```

I want the user to be able to edit the comment to his posts. But when checking access simple user can still edit other (all) comments.

Is this abilty works for cancan?

```
 can :manage, Comment, commentable: {user_id: user.id}
```

Thank you for your help!

***======= update =======***

Sorry that I forgot to show my ability  checking:

```
- can? :manage, @post => Comment
```

And tried to rewrite:

```
= can? :manage, @post.comments.build
```

but I do not like this cheching, because created empty object

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#hash-of-conditions) indicates that the declaration you're using should work as long as you have an association called commentable. When you use that syntax you still get access by users that don't own the associated commentable?
Could the problem be in the ability checking?

**UPDATE**

The problem is in your ability checking. You are checking to see whether the user can manage ANY comment. You need to check whether they can update (or manage if you prefer) the specific comment that they are trying to update.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to show my ability  checking, see update of question

Comment: That's your problem. You are checking capability to manage a generic comment, rather than the specific comment that the user is attempting to update. You need to do something more like `can? :update, @comment` when the user is wanting to edit it.